# Where did "sorry" get its vowel sound?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, vowels

*Sorry* has two pronunciations in my dictionary: `ˈsärē` and `ˈsôrē`. The first is the one I am interested in because, as someone pointed out to me, the *or* pattern in English is nearly always pronounced as "oh-r" not "ah-r". At the time, I couldn't think of any other words that pronounced *or* as "ah-r" but overheard someone say "tomorrow" and realized there are a few others:

- tomorrow
- sorrow
- morrow
- horror (the first *o* and only in some places)

The question is this: Is there a commonality between these words that allow for a `är` (ah-r) pronunciation? Perhaps a similar history? Does the double-r make the difference?

Comment: In General American, I believe tomorrow, sorrow, morrow, borrow, sorry, and sometimes orange is pretty much a complete list of words with /ɒr/ in British English which have become /ɑr/ in American English. The rest have become /ɔr/ (except in New England, the mid-Atlantic, and the Carolinas, as explained in @ESultanik's answer). I don't believe anybody knows why it happened with just these words.

Comment: @PeterShor I certainly have `/ɔr/` **not** `/ɒr/` in *sorrow, morrow, borrow, sorry*, and depending on my mood and the phase of the moon, occasionally in *tomorrow*, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words you list all contain what is called an "intervocalic /r/".  As [danorton](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/12993/danorton) mentioned in [his answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41866/where-did-sorry-get-its-vowel-sound/41867#41867), in [Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) an "o" preceding an intervocalic "r" is pronounced as /ɒ/ (like the "o" in "l**o**t" or "**o**range").  This pronunciation also occurs in Boston, USA.  In [Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_English), the "o" is pronounced  /ɔ/ (as in "c**o**rd").  In much of the [mid-Atlantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_English) (*e.g.*, [New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_dialect), [Philadelphia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_dialect), and the Carolinas), the "o" is pronounced /ɑ/ (as in "c**a**rd").  In [the remainder of the US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English), the pronunciation varies between /ɔ/ and /ɑ/ depending on the word.  The words you gave as examples are usually pronounced with /ɑ/, whereas words like "horrible", "origin", and "Florida" are usually pronounced with /ɔ/.

In conclusion, [this phenomenon varies by dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_r).  It is also related to the "[horse–hoarse merger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse%E2%80%93hoarse_merger#Horse.E2.80.93hoarse_merger)," in which the vowels /ɔ/ and /o/ are merged when preceding an /r/, thus making words like horse/hoarse, for/four, war/wore, or/oar, morning/mourning, *&c.*, homophones.

Answer (score 3):

These two pronunciations are very typical differences in dialect and I suspect that your reference is from an American English dictionary. The first pronunciation is typical of dialects around the U.S. Great Lakes (historically influenced by Irish immigrants — including some of my ancestors) and the second is closer to Standard British ([Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)).